# How to access body in luasocket as binary data?

Tags: lua, luajit

This code:

```
local client = require("socket.http")
local resp = client.request("some_server.com/some_image123.png")
```

How do I get the body -- as binary data / image -- of a response?  Here "resp" isn't that.

Comment: The `some_server.com` needs whole `http://` prefix to work properly. Check second value returned by `request` for error messages, e.g. `local resp, err = client.request...`. If you are getting `301` or `302` statuses you might need to use `luasec` instead of pure `socket`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, had you read the [manual](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html), you'd know this:

> If successful, the simple form returns the response body as a string, followed by the response status code

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you really didn't know where to find that information, but even a quick google search for "luasocket reference" would have brought that page up.

---

EDIT: Or maybe you already knew that, and instead didn't realize that a string in Lua is also a representation of binary data. Same as in any other language, Lua strings are just arrays of bytes under the hood, but other than, for example C, they can contain *any* byte, including `0x00`, so you can use them to store any sort of binary data you want.